# what is difference between both statement?

Tags: class, c#-4.0, generics, collections

Can anyone tell me difference in detail about this two statement ?

```
class  myClass : Dictionary<string,string> {}

class myClass2<Dictionary<string, string>> {}
```

Answer (score 2):

First statement declares a class which inherits `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where key and value are strings.

Second one isn't valid: you can't give a generic argument to a generic class declaration.

Maybe you wanted to ask for something like this:

```
class MyClass2<T> where T : Dictionary<string, string>
```

...which is a `MyClass2` generic class where its generic parameter must be `Dictionary<string, string>` or inherits it.

Comment: Thanks matias fidemraizer